# How could I optimize this algorithm for approximating pi?

Tags: c#, math, pi

I am quite inexperienced in coding, but I have managed to  write this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PiApprox
{

    public class PiApprox
    {
        //side of the rectangle
        public static int s;

        //radius of the circle
        public static int r;

        //indexers of the coordinates, points
        public static int ix;
        public static int iy;

        //current y
        public static decimal cury;
        //without rounding
        public static decimal wcury;

        //amounts of points relative to the circle
        public static decimal inAmount;
        public static decimal onAmount;
        public static decimal outAmount;

        //amount of all points
        public static decimal allAmount;

        //short for inAmount and on onAmount, 
        //used to make the calculations clearer in the final part
        public static decimal inanon;

        //final result, crude approximation of pi
        public static decimal piApprox;


        public static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Calculate();
            }
        }

        public static void Calculate ()
        {
            s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            //calculate the radius of the circle
            r = s / 2;

            //calculate the total amount of points in the grid
            //rectangle area
            allAmount = (decimal) Math.Pow(s, 2);

            //reset values
            inAmount = 0;
            onAmount = 0;
            outAmount = 0;

            //main loop
            //iterate for y, from up to down 
            for (ix = -r; ix <= 0; ix++)
            {
                wcury = (decimal) Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(r, 2) - Math.Pow(ix, 2));
                cury = Math.Floor(wcury);


                outAmount += r - (int)cury;

                if (wcury == cury)
                {
                    onAmount++;
                }

                if (wcury == cury)
                {
                    inAmount += (int)cury;
                }
                else
                {
                    inAmount += (int)cury + 1;
                }
                Result();
            }

            Result();
        }

        public static void Result()
        {
            //total amount of points
            inanon = 4 * (onAmount + inAmount - (r + 1)) + 1;

            //proportion
            piApprox = 4 * (inanon / allAmount);

            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(piApprox);
        }
    }

}
```

The Monte Carlo principle is simple; I calculate the y values 
for the plot f(x) = sqrt(r^2 - ix^2) which represent the first quarter of a circle. I then calculate points within the circle and output it at the end. 
The multiplication on the line piApprox = 4 * (inanon / allAmount);
comes from the proportions of the square and the circle:
 (pi * r^2) / ( (2r) ^ 2 )  ->
 (pi * r ^ 2) / (4 * r ^ 2)  ->  pi / 4

Is there something I could do to speed up the computing?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there are a number of things you could do to speed up the code, especially if you are new to programming and have not made an effort yourself to speed it up. Lacking a _specific_ problem statement, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. It might be appropriate on codereview.stackexchange.com; you could try posting it there. If you want an answer here, you need to explain what you've tried to speed the code up, how you have measured performance, what specific, measurable performance goal you're trying to meet, and why you think it can be met.

Comment: why call `Result()` _every time_ inside the loop? `WriteLine`'ing every time takes a noticeable amount of time overall, so reduce the rate of output as the number of points increases

Comment: This is not Monte-Carlo, there is nothing random about this algorithm. This is just the integration of the curve `sqrt(r*r-x*x)` over the interval `[0,r]` using the most basic integration method. Explore Simpson method or Romberg method for better integration accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're new to C# so I'll just give you a couple hints here.

Several things have potential for improvement:

- `decimal` is slow: it uses software computations. On the other hand, calculations on `int`, `double` and similar are implemented in hardware. Use `int` here, you don't use the decimal part anyway.
- `Math.Pow` is slow. Don't use it for squaring: Replace `Math.Pow(x, 2)` with `x * x`
- `Math.Sqrt` is slow. Instead of comparing `Math.Sqrt(x)` to `y`, compare `x` to `y * y` instead. Or just call it once at the end.
- `Math.Floor` is *slow* :)
- You could use parallelism to leverage multicore CPUs
- You should use local variables as they're more prone for optimization

Bear in mind that when I mean *slow* it's *relative*. All of these operations are extremely fast in an absolute sense - I just mean you could use an even faster alternative.

But there's one thing which is *painfully slow* (such that it's noticeable for a human): `Console`. It got much better on Windows 10, but it's still slow and you're using the console in the hot path of your code. Get rid of these intermediate results.

One more thing, if you use `int` in a division, you'll get an `int` in C#. You need to cast one operand to, say, a `double` before dividing if you want to get the fractional part (as in `(double)x / y`).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. What do you recommend using instead of floor? Would it be better if I had a job completion percentage increment of 5 instead of the calculated value every x?

Comment: I can't use int for final calculations, but float is only precise to 7 digits.

Comment: And I use the floor to determine whether the y is on a specific point.

Comment: How can I compare without using the square root? If I want to know the y, I need to take the square root at some point.

Comment: For positive values of `x`, you can use `(int)x` instead of `(int)Math.Floor(x)` - it's equivalent. Displaying the intermediate value every `5%` (or even 1%) is a good idea. You can use `decimal`, but try to avoid it where it's not needed (you can only use it in the `Result` part for instance). Getting rid of the square root would actually require you to change the algorithm - I just gave you overall hints.